# devexpress XtraChart: Line Chart years in x-axis showing in decimal and unable to set MaxValueInternal for wholerange and visualrange

Tags: c#, charts, devexpress

I am new to dev-express and I was trying to create a Line chart with below data:

[image]

In x-axis is the years and y-axis has the population 
And to plot for all the 3 countries there will be three series.

I have successfully created the chart but the year shows somewhat like this:
[image]

if you see the x-axis it is coming like in decimals although in database year is in YEAR(Mysql)

I tried using

```
diagram.AxisX.VisualRange.Auto = false;
diagram.AxisX.VisualRange.AutoSideMargins = true;
diagram.AxisX.VisualRange.MinValue = 2000;
diagram.AxisX.VisualRange.MaxValue = 2010;
diagram.AxisX.WholeRange.MinValue = 1990;
diagram.AxisX.WholeRange.MaxValue = 2014;
```

Also one more problem I was having I tried using WholeRange.MaxValueInternal and VisualRange.MaxValueInternal
But got below error:
[image]

Also I do know the difference between VisualRange and wholerange but i did not get the importance of MaxValueInternal except that it should be set to double when series' argumentscaletype is datetime or qualitative but how does it effects the series? what is diffrence if we dont use it at all or use it on chart?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused between `MaxValueInternal` and `MaxValueInterval`. You cannot set a value to [`VisualRange.MaxValueInternal`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsRange_MaxValueInternaltopic) property because this property is only have a getter declared.
You can use [`AxisX.NumericScaleOptions`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsAxisBase_NumericScaleOptionstopic) property to set an interval. Just set [`NumericScaleOptions.GridAlignment`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsNumericScaleOptions_GridAlignmenttopic) property to `NumericGridAlignment.Custom` and set [`NumericScaleOptions.CustomGridAlignment`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsNumericScaleOptions_CustomGridAlignmenttopic) property to `YourIntervalValue / 2`.
Here is example:

```
const double interval = 1;

var table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Population_millions", typeof(int));

table.Rows.Add(1, "Europe", 2000, 4000);
table.Rows.Add(2, "America", 2000, 7000);
table.Rows.Add(3, "Africa", 2000, 1000);
table.Rows.Add(4, "Africa", 2005, 2000);
table.Rows.Add(5, "Europe", 2005, 9000);
table.Rows.Add(6, "America", 2005, 6000);
table.Rows.Add(7, "America", 2007, 3000);
table.Rows.Add(8, "Europe", 2007, 1900);
table.Rows.Add(9, "Africa", 2007, 1500);

var chart = new ChartControl();

chart.DataSource = table;
chart.SeriesDataMember = "Country";
chart.BindToData(ViewType.Line, table, "Country", "Year", new string[] { "Population_millions" });

var diagram = (XYDiagram)chart.Diagram;

diagram.AxisX.NumericScaleOptions.GridAlignment = NumericGridAlignment.Custom;
diagram.AxisX.NumericScaleOptions.CustomGridAlignment = interval / 2;

diagram.AxisX.WholeRange.MinValue = 1990;
diagram.AxisX.WholeRange.MaxValue = 2014;
diagram.AxisX.VisualRange.Auto = false;
diagram.AxisX.VisualRange.AutoSideMargins = true;
diagram.AxisX.VisualRange.MinValue = 2000;
diagram.AxisX.VisualRange.MaxValue = 2010;

diagram.EnableAxisXScrolling = true;
diagram.EnableAxisXZooming = true;

chart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

Controls.Add(chart);
```

And here is result of example:
[image: Result]

Comment: also if i assign AxisX.NumericScaleOptions.CustomMeasureUnit = 5 for same code as in ur answer the lines of chart are becoming straight..

Comment: @Silver According to your last comment, I think, `MeasureUnit` is not what you are looking for. Try `GridAlignment` instead. I have updated my answer.

Comment: thanks but then the problem as per my question year in x-axis showing in decimal resumes..

Comment: @Silver It seems like something strange. What is your version of DevExpress?

Comment: @Silver My version is 14.1.6. Try to set `diagram.AxisX.Label.TextPattern = "{V:#}";`.

Comment: 13.2.8.0 does not have TextPattern.

Comment: @Silver I have no idea how can I help you. Try to contact DevExpress Support.